# Make multiple IDE's code formatters produce the same results

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, intellij-idea, code-formatting

Most IDEs provide some kind of code formatter, turning your source code pretty and readable upon key press. They can be configured more or less liberately, but if two code formatters have different opinions on how some code should be wrapped or indented, this is likely to produce unnecessary inserts/deletes in diffs and unnecessary problems on merges.

Is there a known way, e.g. certain, documented configuration settings, which lead the code formatters of Eclipse, Netbeans and IntelliJ IDEA to produce equal results on some java code?

Answer (score 5):

There is a plugin for maven that will check the style of the code to ensure that any code committed to an SCM conforms to a specified style: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/.
I'm not sure about the style settings in individual IDEs.

Comment: That plugin exists as an Eclipseplugin aswell.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ has a [plug in](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=6546) to import eclipse code formatting settings: